# Control the call and media functions of an iOS device from Raspberry Pi

Tags: ios

*This is a follow up question to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/control-ios-device-from-raspberry-pi)*

The BLE shield suggested by Derek Knight in the referenced Question may be great to either control your RPi from your iPhone, or send data back to your iPhone for processing with a custom app. However I am wondering if there is a way to easily control from a RPi (or equivalent) the basic functions of an iOS device that can be controlled with headsets or bluetooth accessories like the ones sold by Satechi. If those can without any specific permission or jailbreaking Answer/Hang-up calls, Turn volume up or down and mute, Go to the previous/next slide/track, Pause/play and Press home button, there should be a way to do that from a RPi.

Does anyone know a simple hardware (Bluetooth shield? USB connection?) and software package (Ubuntu package? Python module?) to do that?